# Gdiplusshutdown results in exit code 1

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi+

when my app is exited i see the following in the debugger console.

```
The thread '_threadstartex' (0xd48) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '_threadstartex' (0xf80) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '_threadstartex' (0x190) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '_threadstartex' (0xaa0) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '_threadstartex' (0x67c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '_threadstartex' (0x6f0) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '_threadstartex' (0x9e4) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '_threadstartex' (0xf04) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win64 Thread' (0xbcc) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win64 Thread' (0xe08) has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 'Win64 Thread' (0x9a4) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win64 Thread' (0x3a0) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'BFX_App.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msxml6.dll'
'BFX_App.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsCodecsExt.dll'
The program '[2148] BFX_App.exe: Native' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

I traced the thread exiting with exit code 1 to a call to `Gdiplus::GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);`
 in the destructor of my app. I am not really sure why this call is resulting in a thread with exit code 1. I would appreciate if anyone can help me find what is causing this error.

Thanks,
Abhinay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short summary: Nothing to be concerned about.

The runtime library is just notifying you that threads are exiting.  Whether or not its related to GDI+ is unproven (since its happening in your app shutdown sequence when lots of other things are getting killed).  This type of debug spew is common to see in the visual studio debugger.

Something to consider: don't bother calling GdiplusShutdown.  When your process exits, any memory or resources allocated by the GDI+ library will get cleaned up anyway.

Comment: Thanks selbie. I read somewhere that it should not affect the program execution but wanted to make sure i am not missing anything. :-)

Comment: The odds are it _is_ related to GDI+ as the MS testers also [get it](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1134416/breakpoints-in-gdiplus-startup-shutdown-return-cod.html).